# Is it possible to import parent module from sub class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, module, export

I have two files with their own modules, *Sub.js* and *Parent.js*

Parent.js:

```
import Sub from "/.Sub.js"
export default class Parent {
    static createSomething(){
        new Sub();
    }
}
```

Sub.js:

```
import Parent from "/.Parent.js"
export default class Sub extends Parent {
    contructor(){}
}
```

With that I get error:

*ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration`X' before initialization*

Sub-module cannot be used because Parent-module is needed, but importing Parent-module requires importing Sub-module, I think?

This could be resolved by putting them in the same file, but I wonder if there is a way of keeping them as seperates files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When implementing such circular dependencies, make sure that the file you're using in other code doesn't contain top-level `export` declarations that require the other file. In your case:

- If you import `Sub` in some other file, its top-level `export` requires `Parent` which requires `Sub`, then it's impossible to resolve: the snake bites its own tail
- If you import `Parent` in some other file, its top-level `export` doesn't need `Sub` immediately (only when `createSomething` is being called). In that case, the `Parent` `export` fully resolves, then the `Sub` file is able to resolve its own `export` as well.

As a general recommendation, I would advise against circular dependencies. However, this is a possible workaround that leverages the dynamic [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) syntax instead of the static one:

### parent.ts

```
export default class Parent {
    static async createSomething() {
        const Sub = await import('./sub').then(x => x.default);
        return new Sub;
    }
}

Parent.createSomething().then(console.log);
```

### sub.ts

```
import Parent from "./parent"
export default class Sub extends Parent {
    contructor() { }
}
```

Comment: how did you fix this problem? I also want to know. can you give some code example?

Comment: @Yiffany I did not fix this problem since it was Chlodio's one. As a general recommendation, avoid circular dependencies.

Comment: is there a walkaround that I can `export default class Sub extends import Parent from "/.Parent.js"`? Not require, just import?

Comment: The static `import` cannot work for this case, I've added a possible solution with the dynamic `import `