# JS: How to create child class from a parent class in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

How to avoid circular references at the same time create some child classes from the parent class? And keep the constrain that each class need to reside in a different file.

```js
//Parent.mjs:
import Sub from "/.Sub.mjs"
export default class Parent {
    static createSomething(){
        new Sub();
    }
}


//Sub.mjs:
import Parent from "/.Parent.mjs"
export default class Sub extends Parent {
    contructor(){}
}
```

This question was originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67576928/is-it-possible-to-import-parent-module-from-sub-class-in-javascript/67577157#comment132588655_67577157). But there is no solution under that question. If I really want to create a subclass from the superclass what code should I write?

Comment: The superclass shouldn't need to know anything about a subclass. That is a code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent class should not need to know anything about subclass(es).

I don't see why the parent class would need a static method for creating a subclass,
but if you feel you really, really need that, then extend the `Parent` class object from within the Sub.mjs file:

Parent.mjs:

```
export default class Parent {
}
```

Sub.mjs:

```
import Parent from "/.Parent.mjs"
Parent.createSomething = function () {
    return new Sub();
}
export default class Sub extends Parent {
    constructor(){} // fixed typo here
}
```

Still, I think it is a bad idea to define such a function on the parent class. This looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). The original reason that made you look for such a function in the first place, certainly has a better way to be solved that doesn't involve a parent class that needs to know about a subclass.